# angular 7 production build failure

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-service-worker, ng-zorro-antd

I created an angular 7 project. Added [Ng-zorro](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd) in my project. Everything works nicely when developing using ng serve. I added serviceworker using the following command:

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

in my tsconfig file, i added the following line:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": true
}
```

Everything works fine while using ng serve or npm start. But when i try ng build --prod it gives the following error:

```
ERROR in : Template parse errors:
The pipe 'nzI18n' could not be found ("down-menu-item ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-disabled">
    {{ nzNotFoundContent ? nzNotFoundContent[ERROR ->] : ('Select.notFoundContent' | nzI18n) }}
  </li>
  <li
"): /Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/Projects/ngx-boilerplate/node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.d.ts.ɵbo.html@11:44
The pipe 'nzFilterOptionPipe' could not be found ("
    [nzMode]="nzMode"
    [compareWith]="compareWith"
    *ngFor="let op[ERROR ->]tion of listOfNzOptionComponent | nzFilterOptionPipe : nzSearchValue : nzFilterOption : nzServerSearc"): /Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/Projects/ngx-boilerplate/node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.d.ts.ɵbo.html@24:18
The pipe 'nzSubFilterOptionPipe' could not be found ("
  </li>
  <li
    *ngFor="let g[ERROR ->]roup of listOfNzOptionGroupComponent | nzSubFilterOptionPipe : nzSearchValue : nzFilterOption : nzSer"): /Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/Projects/ngx-boilerplate/node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.d.ts.ɵbo.html@31:17
The pipe 'nzFilterOptionPipe' could not be found ("
        [nzMode]="nzMode"
        [compareWith]="compareWith"
        *ngFor="let op[ERROR ->]tion of group.listOfNzOptionComponent | nzFilterOptionPipe : nzSearchValue : nzFilterOption : nzServe"): /Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/Projects/ngx-boilerplate/node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.d.ts.ɵbo.html@46:22
The pipe 'nzFilterOptionPipe' could not be found ("
    [nzMode]="nzMode"
    [compareWith]="compareWith"
    *ngFor="let op[ERROR ->]tion of listOfTagOption | nzFilterOptionPipe : nzSearchValue : nzFilterOption : nzServerSearch "
    "): /Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/Projects/ngx-boilerplate/node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.d.ts.ɵbo.html@59:18
```

Comment: Did u import the `PipesModule`

Comment: Where are you importing ng-zorro main module? In app.module or a lazy-loaded module? If it's a lazy-loaded module, this error could occur

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with lib version, try to downgrade your library